# How to retrieve iOS or Android keyboard colour in code?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, keyboard

I'm making an app in React Native and I wanted to make a keyboard accessory view which would basically extend the keyboard on the device, so it would have to have the exact same colour as the keyboard.

I'm using `KeyboardAccessoryView` for Android and `InputAccessoryView` for iOS to do this.

**My question is - is there any way to retrieve the colour of the keyboard the device is using in code for both iOS and Android?**

I thought maybe the `PlatformColor` function in React Native would have this, but I find nothing mentioning keyboards there.

Comment: I will be stunned if this is possible on Android. Not only is that information likely to be unavailable, there is no requirement for a keyboard to use only one color. Keyboards routinely use several colors, such as the background, the keycaps, and the symbols on those keycaps. Even if we interpret "exact same colour as the keyboard" as referring to the background, there is no requirement for that background to be a single color. It could be a gradient fill, for example.